# Understanding ActionExecutingContext.Result within an ActionFilterAtrribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cross-domain, actionfilterattribute, onactionexecuting

I recently read this code that makes an MVC Web API allow CORS (Cross origing resource sharing). I understand that the `ActionFilterAtrribute` makes this a filter, but I'm not sure what's going on in this class: `AllowCORS`.

```
public class AllowCORS : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

So basically, if the request method we receive is a `HttpOPTIONS` we do something which I don't quite understand in this case. Otherwise, we do something else that I'm not sure about either?

What's actually going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ActionFilterAttribute` class, `OnActionExecuting` executes just before the execution of the controller action on which `ActionFilterAttribute` attribute is placed.

If you override `OnActionExecuting` function, it allows you to execute any certain code before the execution of controller action. In your case:

```
if(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
{
    filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();
}
```

If the request is `HttpOPTIONS` then before execution of controller action, the code returns an empty response to the client.

And if the request is of some other type:

```
else
{
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

It will allow the controller action to execute and return response to the client.